# What is the difference between a HashMap and a TreeMap?

Tags: java

I started learning Java. When would I use a HashMap over a TreeMap?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't just for the question asker but also for other people looking for answers. Thus it is perfectly fine for me if I find an answer here that is also contained in some book I don't have...

Answer (score 267, accepted):

[`TreeMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is an example of a [`SortedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), which means that the order of the keys can be sorted, and when iterating over the keys, you can expect that they will be in order.

[`HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) on the other hand, makes no such guarantee.  Therefore, when iterating over the keys of a `HashMap`, you can't be sure what order they will be in.

`HashMap` will be more efficient in general, so use it whenever you don't care about the order of the keys.

Comment: `HashMap` is more time-efficient. A `TreeMap` is more space-efficient.

Comment: TreeMap only works with Comparable objects, HashMap only works with objects with a suitable hashCode() implementation.

Comment: @erickson: could you post a reference/link to back up this statement pls?

Comment: `TreeMap` search complexity is O(log(N)), `HashMap` is O(1) with a good hashCode().

Comment: HashMap allows null key and null values (Only one null key is allowed). If TreeMap uses natural ordering or its comparator,  does not allow null keys, an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 69):

`HashMap` is implemented by Hash Table while `TreeMap` is implemented by `Red-Black tree`. The main difference between `HashMap` and `TreeMap` actually reflect the main difference between a `Hash` and a `Binary Tree` , that is, when iterating,  TreeMap guarantee can the key order which is determined by either element's compareTo() method or a comparator set in the TreeMap's constructor.

Take a look at [following diagram](http://pierrchen.blogspot.com/2014/03/java-collections-framework-cheat-sheet.html).

[image]

Comment: Is that mean randomly fetching in TreeMap is faster than HashMap ?

Answer (score 35):

To sum up:

- HashMap: Lookup-array structure, based on hashCode(), equals() implementations, O(1) runtime complexity for inserting and searching, unsorted
- TreeMap: Tree structure, based on compareTo() implementation, O(log(N)) runtime complexity for inserting and searching, sorted

Taken from: [HashMap vs. TreeMap](http://arnosoftwaredev.blogspot.com/2010/10/hash-tables-vs-binary-search-tree.html)

Comment: The complexity o a HashMap is O(1+a). Dependent on the hashCode function "a" can reach "n" in the worst case.

Answer (score 25):

Use `HashMap` most of the times but use `TreeMap` when you need the key to be sorted (when you need to iterate the keys).

Comment: What's a real world example where it matters if the keys are sorted?

Answer (score 14):

I'll talk about the **HashMap** and **TreeMap** implementation in Java:

- HashMap -- implement basic map interface

  1. implemented by an array of buckets, each bucket is a LinkedList of entries
  2. running time of basic operations: put(), average O(1), worst case O(n), happens when the table is resized; get(), remove(), average O(1)
  3. not synchronized, to synchronize it: `Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));`
  4. Iteration order of the map is unpredictable.
- TreeMap -- implement navigable map interface

  1. implemented by a red-black tree
  2. running time of basic operations: put(), get(), remove(), worst case O(lgn)
  3. not synchronized, to synchronize it: `SortedMap m = Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap(...));`
  4. provide ordered iteration. higherKey(), lowerKey() can be used to get the successor and predecessor of a given key.

To sum, the biggest difference between HashMap and TreeMap is that TreeMap implements `NavigableMap<K,V>`, which provide the feature of ordered iteration. Besides, both HashMap and TreeMap are members of Java Collection framework. You can investigate the [source code of Java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.KeyIterator.next%28%29) to know more about their implementations.

Answer (score 8):

You almost always use `HashMap`, you should only use `TreeMap` if you need your keys to be in a specific order.

Answer (score 7):

`HashMap` is used for fast lookup, whereas `TreeMap` is used for sorted iterations over the map.

Answer (score 6):

Along with sorted key store one another difference is with TreeMap, developer can give (String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) with String keys, so then the comparator ignores case of key while performing comparison of keys on map access. This is not possible to give such option with HashMap - it is always case sensitive comparisons in HashMap.

Comment: Not necessary.  If you really want this, you can simply make a decorator for a map, for which for all things involving key input, you make it all upper/lower case, and delegate to the decorated map.  By doing so, it is not that difficult to have a "case insensitive" hashmap.  Anyway, this answer is probably a bit off-topic: you are only talking about a very specific use case of treemap, for which I don't see it being very meaningful as a comparison between hashmap/treemap