# How to sort HashMap by referring another HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have two `HashMap` in Java.

First one contains a key and its value. Where second contains an evaluation index (order) of that keys. I want to sort the first map by referring to the second map.

First HashMap `<key, value>`

```
<"C","ccc">
<"D","ddd">
<"A","aaa">
<"B","bbb">
```

Second HashMap `<key, value>`

```
<"0","A">
<"1","B">
<"2","C">
<"3","D">
```

Result should be

```
<"A","aaa">
<"B","bbb">
<"C","ccc">
<"D","ddd">
```

Looping this two map and checking comparing keys is simple but not efficient. Any efficient idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Java Stream API. First, sort the second map entrySet by key then map second map's value as key and get first map's value by value of the second map and then collect as `LinkedHashMap` using `Collectors.toMap`

```
secondMap.entrySet().stream()
         .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, k -> firstMap.get(k.getValue()),
                                                          (x, y) -> y, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

If you use LinkedHashMap/TreeMap ordered by key for the second map then you don't need to sort the keys. See demo [here](https://onlinegdb.com/rk5OTGWfw)

Comment: What if the first map is Map<String, Object>. Your code doesn't work

Comment: @kandarp It's working see here [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rJzlwWbMP)

Comment: `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>` can be `Map.entry`.

Comment: @kandarp If the second HashMap is `{"0000000"="A", "1111111"="B", "2222222"="C", "3333333"="D"}`, the result is `{"C"="ccc", "D"="ddd", "B"="bbb", "A"="aaa"}`. Is that all right?

Comment: @saka1029 Are you trying to say this case ? https://onlinegdb.com/S1tb4zbGw It's working for me.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks Since OP says `Second HashMap`, `res1` is meaningless. `res2` uses a different code than your answer.

Comment: I think `map` step is not needed at all. The same transformation can be done inside `toMap`

Answer (score 1):

First of all `HashMap` is not ordered collections. The key-value pairs in HashMap are ordered based on the value of hashCode() result of keys. So I would say you can't keep sorted values in `HashMap`.

Instead, you can use `LinkedHashMap` - it will be ordered with order of insertion.

And for your solution, i would do:

```
HashMap<String, String> firstMap = ...
HashMap<String, String> secondMap = ...
LinkedHashMap<String, String> orderedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < secondMap.size(); ++i) {
   String key = secondMap.get(String.valueOf(i));
   orderedMap.put(key, firstMap.get(key));
}
```

Did not run this code, but it should work.

Alternatively, you can use `TreeMap` that is ordered based on `Comparable` interface of the keys.

And to answer what is better to use - TreeMap or LinkedHashMap - depends on how actually you are using this map later. In most cases LinkedHashMap is enough, although if you need to, for example, get the closest greater element to some key, then TreeMap is a choice.

There are some comparison between HashMap and TreeMap
[What is the difference between a HashMap and a TreeMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444359/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hashmap-and-a-treemap)

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the values of secondMap and collect the related key, value set in the map:

```
Map<String, String> result = secondMap.values().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), firstMap::get, (x,y)-> x, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Try this:

```
Map<String, String> firstMap = new HashMap<>();
firstMap.put("C", "ccc");
firstMap.put("D", "ddd");
firstMap.put("A", "aaa");
firstMap.put("B", "bbb");

Map<String, String> secondMap = new HashMap<>();
secondMap.put("0", "A");
secondMap.put("1", "B");
secondMap.put("2", "C");
secondMap.put("3", "D");

Map<String, String> result = secondMap.values().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), firstMap::get, (x,y)-> x, LinkedHashMap::new));
System.out.println(result);
```