# How to insert multiple random key, value pairs into a sorted dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, insert

The code below generates random key, value pairs in a dictionary and then sorts the dictionary. I am wondering how to `insert 100 random key, value pairs` into sorted dictionary and keep it sorted.

```
from random import randrange
mydict = {}
for i in range(10):
   mydict['key'+str(i)] = randrange(10)
sort_mydic=sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: Python's dict is a hash table. It is not an array or tree. Sorted keys doesn't make a hash table faster. Why do you want a sorted dict? What operations do you need to optimize? How fast is fast enough? Please tell us the hard numbers: number of keys, sorts, insertions, and retrievals per seconds. Is this done on hard disk or in memory? What is the read/write pattern of this dict? Otherwise, we can't choose the balance point between performance and convenience for you. We don't need the fastest for everything. We just need to be fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description above, I would skip the step of creating the dictionary. If you start from non-empty dictionary, then run the code above. Once it is set up, use `bisect` and `insert` as below.

```
new_item = randrange(10)
new_key = 'key' + str(new_item)
# find the index where to insert
idx = bisect.bisect(sort_mydic, (new_key, -1)) # the second argument should be smaller than any value
# check if the key is already used or not
if idx == len(sort_mydic) or sort_mydic[idx][0] != new_key:
    sort_mydic.insert(idx, (new_key, new_item))
else:
    # update the value -- as in dictionary
    sort_mydic[idx] = (new_key, new_item)
```

In case you need to retrieve an item.

```
def get_item(key):
    idx = bisect.bisect(sort_mydic, (key, -1))
    if idx == len(sort_mydic) or sort_mydic[idx][0] != key:
        return None # there is no such item
  
    else:
        return sort_mydic[idx][1]
```

Comment: it raised with <' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str for line idx

Comment: Fixed the typo, sorry

Comment: If `idx==len(sort_mydic)`, then I use the insert method will act as an append. No error.

Comment: The idea of sorting keys requires sorting them very often. You may store two data structured: dictionary and the sorted list of keys, but... what is the benefit of using the sorted list of keys in the first place? Simpler code should be preferred at all times.

Comment: I think: 1. Sorting array of keys is faster than sorting dict. 2. Sorted keys don't make dict faster. 3. Keep keys sort. Sort often. -> More speed up for sorted keys + unsorted dict over sorted dict.

Comment: Java has both hash map and tree map. That makes sense: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444359/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hashmap-and-a-treemap

Comment: Your code inset just single random pair. I need to insert multiple random numbers e.g., 100 or 1000 numbers.

Comment: Bob, you can write the loop.

Comment: I add a loop and it just adds the numbers to sort_mydic and the final dict is not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't use `OrderedDict` for this purpose? That's what it is meant for. Maybe something like this (haven't checked that it compiles yet):

```
from random import randrange
from collections import OrderedDict

mydict = {}
for i in range(10):
   mydict['key'+str(i)] = randrange(10)
sort_mydic = OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

`OrderedDict` behaves like any other dictionary except that it is guaranteed to be in insertion order and can be rearranged as necessary. In fact, there's probably a "better" way than the above to do what you want that does not involve an intermediate `dict`.

Comment: I tried that before and then I was thinking how to insert multiple random key, value pairs into it.

Comment: The other half of your question is the same as for `dict` - use the `update` method. `OrderedDict` is just a `dict` with particular behavior. What's happening on the last line is that a temporary list of tuples is being created, which when passed to the `OrderedDict` constructor creates one from it. You can do the same with an ordinary `dict` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Order of keys in a dictionary is insertion order for python 3.6+.

Sorting a dict in older versions of python is impossible.

- [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Solution:

- Insert new key-value pairs
- Sort

```py
from random import randrange


def make_rand_dict(prefix, n_items=2):
    keys = [prefix + str(i) for i in range(n_items)]
    return {k: randrange(10) for k in keys}


def sort_dict(d):
    return {k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items())}


def main():
    # Make dict with sorted and random 
    # key-value pair
    original = make_rand_dict("key", n_items=2)
    original = sort_dict(original)

    # New random key-value pairs
    # Set n_items=100 for more pairs
    update = make_rand_dict("aye", n_items=2)

    # Insert the random key-value pair from 
    # the update dict into the original dict
    original.update(update)
    print("before sort:", original)

    # Sort the dict
    sorted_combined = sort_dict(original)
    print("after sort:", sorted_combined)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```
before sort: {'key0': 9, 'key1': 7, 'aye0': 2, 'aye1': 4}
after sort: {'aye0': 2, 'aye1': 4, 'key0': 9, 'key1': 7}
```

Comment: Thanks, and then how to insert multiple random key, value pairs into sorted one as I described in question.

Comment: the `update` dict has multiple random key-value pairs. `original.update(update)` inserts the update dict's random key-value pair into the original dict. I rename `make_dict(...)` to `make_rand_dict(...)` to reflect this.

Comment: I want to see how much time takes to insert 10 or 100 key, value pairs into a sorted dictionary, I am not sure how to insert different number of key, value pairs into your code

Comment: If you want performance, then I would just sort a list of keys instead of the key-value pair. The advantage of dict is fast insertion, deletion and look up. It is not the most memory efficient structure. Sorting key is enough. No need to sort key-value pair.

Comment: it raised with' make_rand_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_items''

Comment: You are updating dictionary and then sorting again. This cannot give us the performance of insertion in dictionary. It's more sorting than insertion. I need to insert into sorted dictionary by finding right index for each key.

Comment: I know Python's dict is a hash table. I want to measure run time of insertion of n = 10, n = 100, n = 1000 key, value pairs into a dictionary and compare with other structures.